# Flutter camera flip the image

Tags: flutter, dart

I am taking an image from the camera and just showing it in a widget in xFile format but the issue is it's flipping the image.

I am using `camera: ^0.9.4+5`

```
  void onTakePictureButtonPressed() {
    takePicture().then((XFile? file) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          imageFile = file;
        });
        if (file != null) {
          print('Picture saved to ${file.path}');
          filePath = file.path;
          setState(() {
            retake = true;
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }

  Future<XFile?> takePicture() async {
    final CameraController? cameraController = _controller;
    if (cameraController == null || !cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
      print('Error: select a camera first.');
      return null;
    }

    if (cameraController.value.isTakingPicture) {
      // A capture is already pending, do nothing.
      return null;
    }

    try {
      XFile file = await cameraController.takePicture();
      return file;
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Maybe I can show it by just rotating my image widget but it will save and flip images in my Database.